# 403 Error when test in Schema testing tool

Tags: .htaccess, schema

I am facing an issue with a `.` in in urls

My url is: https://domainsanalytics.com/stackoverflow.com

It works well but when I validate in the schema testing tool it shows me 403 error

https://search.google.com/test/rich-results/result?id=kakYpaAlDDmSHY9q3z8S8A

but other links work well , which don't have a `.`

I google a bit and figure out its issue in htaccess (hope so). but My efforts not not working,

Any help regarding this problem will be appreciated.

---

Working URL : https://domainsanalytics.com/keyword/stackoverflow

Not wokring URL : https://domainsanalytics.com/stackoverflow.com

Comment: "when I validate in the schema testing tool" - You don't need to use an external tool, just requesting that URL in the browser results in a 403 HTTP response status. If you think it's an issue with `.htaccess` then you need to include the contents of your `.htaccess` file in you question. (Although it's hard to imagine how this could be an `.htaccess` issue, since your page appears to be correctly rendered by your backend.)

Comment: I didnt get the meanin of "just requesting that URL in the browser results in a 403 HTTP response status" , can you please eleborate... @MrWhite

Comment: Those pages are returning a 403 "error". Any user visiting those pages containing a `.` are getting a 403 response. I'm only saying that because you seem to imply that the 403 error is somehow unique to the "schema testing tool", but you only have to check the HTTP response in the browser to see the 403 Forbidden response code.